# how to use argv[] in a function that need LPCOLESTR

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, directshow

I have a project that uses in wich  a function uses a parameter from type LPCOLESTR

```
 HRESULT BuilGraph(IGraphBuilder *pGraph,LPCOLESTR dstFile)
```

my question is how can I use argv[1] and put it in dstFile, I tried :

```
LPCOLESTR somevar =OLESTR(argv[1]) ;
```

thanks to Roman and Joachim  I change a litle bit my code any it's look like this now :
       char pathstuff[50];
       sprintf(pathstuff,"C:\Users\engine\Desktop\engine%s.avi",argv[1]);

so I get the path video name, knowing that argv[1] will be a number, how can I convert it to

```
 LPCOLESTR  ???
```

it didn't work, any Idea how solve this.
thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to believe they're still using these hideous types from 1990....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LPCOLESTR` is another name for `const WCHAR*`, so you need to do conversion (a multitude of questions on SO on that). If you are using ATL or MFC, it could be as simple as this:

```
CString sValue(argv[1]);
USES_CONVERSION;
BuilGraph (CT2COLE(sValue), ...);
```

With plain C you will use `mbstowcs` as Joachim suggests, or API directly - [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

UPD:

```
 wchar_t pathstuff[50]; 
 swprintf(pathstuff, L"C:\\Users\\engine\\Desktop\\engine%hs.avi", argv[1]);
 LPCOLESTR x = pathstuff;
```

Comment: thanks for help Roman, I edited my question, and I'm not using MFC or ATL

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `LPCOLESTR` is a wide-character string pointer (i.e. a pointer to `wchar_t`), while the strings in the argument array is normal narrow-character strings.

You can use [`mbstowcs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1f9b8cy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to convert a normal string pointer to a wide character string pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Also, _bstr_t (in comdef.h) is a simple way of converting. You can assign either type and can cast it to either type.

G